# Slicing dataset for relevant information

Tags: r

I have a large dataset showing the `social network links` in a corpus. I want to extract just the entities from this corpus. Within the dataset (sample below), the entities can be extracted by capturing the first set of values in the `entity2` column for the first entity in each paragraph.

My sample dataset:

```
structure(list(X = c(6166L, 6168L, 6170L, 6175L, 6177L, 6180L, 
34062L, 34063L, 34064L, 34065L, 34066L), entity1 = c("Epicurus", 
"Epicurus", "Epicurus", "Charles Lamb", "Charles Lamb", "Roman", 
"Egypt", "Egypt", "Egypt", "India", "India"), type1 = c("person", 
"person", "person", "person", "person", "group", "geopolitical area", 
"geopolitical area", "geopolitical area", "geopolitical area", 
"geopolitical area"), entity2 = c("Epic", "Charles Lamb", "Roman", 
"Charles Lamb", "Roman", "Roman", "Egypt", "India", "Arabia", 
"India", "Arabia"), type2 = c("person", "person", "group", "person", 
"group", "group", "geopolitical area", "geopolitical area", "geopolitical area", 
"geopolitical area", "geopolitical area"), text = c("plutarch.txt", 
"plutarch.txt", "plutarch.txt", "plutarch.txt", "plutarch.txt", 
"plutarch.txt", "civilization.txt", "civilization.txt", "civilization.txt", 
"civilization.txt", "civilization.txt"), paragraph = c(49L, 49L, 
49L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
```

would just include the rows for `Epicurus` and `Egypt`. Dataset is 150,000 lines, so will need to be done programmatically. The paragraphs are numbered in the respective column, and these numbers reset for each work, so they won't be unique. I'm not sure if `tidyverse` has anything for this, or if I need to do something like extracting the first set of rows, with duplicated values in the `entity1` column for each paragraph.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Would you mind also adding the expected output of your sample dataset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
df |>
  group_by(paragraph, text) |>
  filter(entity1 == first(entity1))

+ # A tibble: 6 × 7
# Groups:   paragraph, text [2]
      X entity1  type1             entity2      type2            text  paragraph
  <int> <chr>    <chr>             <chr>        <chr>            <chr>     <int>
1  6166 Epicurus person            Epic         person           plut…        49
2  6168 Epicurus person            Charles Lamb person           plut…        49
3  6170 Epicurus person            Roman        group            plut…        49
4 34062 Egypt    geopolitical area Egypt        geopolitical ar… civi…        15
5 34063 Egypt    geopolitical area India        geopolitical ar… civi…        15
6 34064 Egypt    geopolitical area Arabia       geopolitical ar… civi…        15
```

Comment: Looks like this works! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, .SD[1], by = paragraph]
```

for big data, this option may be effective

```
df[df[, .I[1], by = paragraph]$V1, ]

       X  entity1             type1 entity2             type2             text paragraph
1:  6166 Epicurus            person    Epic            person     plutarch.txt        49
2: 34062    Egypt geopolitical area   Egypt geopolitical area civilization.txt        15
```